# Delphi Set the Views of Excel Worksheet Error

Tags: excel, delphi-7, pascal

I am tryin to make the views of the Excel file `ActiveSheet` to normal view.

But I am getting this error about the xlNormalView.

[image: Error undeclared identifier]

What's wrong with the code and how can i get it right and working?

I tried to follow the example to use xlNormalView from this link:
https://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/en/showcode.php?id=156

But still getting the error above.

Comment: Please don't post images of code. Use the 'Edit' button beneath the tags and replace the image with text, thank you. And while you edit your question, please expand it to a [mre], that is code that we can copy paste into Delphi editor and run.

Comment: I don't remember whether Delphi-7 included any type library files for Excel. Do you have for example a file like "Excel2000.pas" or similar in your project (in `uses` clause)? Are there plenty more errors like the ones you show?

Comment: Ok, I fired up an old machine and the Delphi-7 installation did come with the needed file(s). Add the file ...\Borland\Delphi7\Ocx\Servers\Excel2000.pas to your project files and refer to `Excel2000` in the `uses` clause in your Delphi code.

Comment: Thanks for the advice about the image of code and the help, will try that solution later and hope that will work in my case.

Comment: I just tried and it works, thanks a lot for your answer